# Blurring ArcGIS map view

Tags: android, maps, arcgis, blur, 500px

I am trying to make some fancy design with some menu that would switch/configure visible layers of ArcGIS map.

I tried to use promising library: [500px-android-blur](https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur) but I failed on blurring maps. Here is what the blur effect should look like:

[image: blur effect]

I am attaching [demo project](https://github.com/wedkarz/500px-android-blur/tree/arcgis_blur_maps) which is my variation over 500px lib example (just replacing imageviews with arc gis map). Unfortunatelly it doesn't work as expected. Notice that the map is faded but not blurred. Any ideas why it doesn't work or how to fix it?
Or maybe is there other library for blurring views that could possibly work with ArcGIS maps?

Here is the result:

[image: ArcGis blur image]

Comment: "Unfortunatelly it doesn't work as expected." Can you please explain what you expect to see?

Comment: I have submitted an edit to the question to reflect what I think you tried to ask.

Comment: @GaryS. thanks, that's what I am asking for.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I don't know how to answer it though. :-( I see your GitHub issue at https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur/issues/24 . Hopefully the people responsible for that repo will reply!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this library https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry where you can adjust the parameters.